# How do you include a "$" in the code generated in a CodeSnippet?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to include the following in my C# code snippet into my controller:

```
return NotFound($"Could not find item with id of {command.ID}");
```

When I try to add it to the code snippet and execute the snippet, everything after the `(` is not there.

Comment: @Aybe Yes it did.  I did the following:  <Literal Editable="true">
    <ID>dollar</ID>
    <ToolTip>Replace the dollar sign character</ToolTip>
    <Default>$</Default>
    <Function></Function>
</Literal>
Usage (line breaks are added for clarity on Stack Overflow, not in the original.):

    string errMessage = $dollar$"Error occurred in
       {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Module}, in procedure
       {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}: {ex.Message}".ToString();

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
<Literal Editable="true">
    <ID>dollar</ID>
    <ToolTip>Replace the dollar sign character</ToolTip>
    <Default>$</Default>
    <Function></Function>
</Literal>
```

Usage (line breaks are added for clarity on Stack Overflow, not in the original.):

```
string errMessage = $dollar$"Error occurred in
   {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Module}, in procedure
   {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}: {ex.Message}".ToString();
```